# Running Spring Boot application but Jenkins hijacks the port

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, tcpserver

I am following the IntelliJ "Hello World" Spring Boot tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kOGdZmpSDI) and when I run the application it sets up the Tomcat server on port 8080, as expected, but when I go to localhost:8080 the Jenkins login page will appear instead as it was previously ran in a Docker container.

Is there a way to check what is running on Tomcat or a way to remove Jenkins entirely?

I have already deleted all running containers and images on Docker desktop and uninstalled Docker, but this issue still persists.

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to using Spring Boot as well as Docker - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default springboot uses port 8080,you can change the port from 8080 to someother port,you  can configure this in your application.properties file

```
Server.port= anyportnumber
```

I think this is the one you are looking for!,,Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I saw something about configuring which port the application runs on, but was unsure where to add the code and I'm using Spring security so the login page threw me off, but this worked